# What is this (non-lambda?) "=>" variable definition in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I'm looking at Protocol Buffers for C#, and [there's code like this](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/Reflection/FileDescriptor.cs):

```
public sealed class FileDescriptor : IDescriptor
{
    // snip

    /// <value>
    /// The file name.
    /// </value>
    public string Name => Proto.Name;

    /// <summary>
    /// The package as declared in the .proto file. This may or may not
    /// be equivalent to the .NET namespace of the generated classes.
    /// </summary>
    public string Package => Proto.Package;

    // etc.
```

[`=>` seems to be the lambda operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx), but this doesn't look much like a lambda. What's going on here?

Comment: it's a duplicate, it was asked couple of days back as well, but its old duplicate

Comment: That's c# 6.0, it's like creating this: public string Name{ get{ return Proto.Name; } set{ Proto.Name = value; }}

Comment: Voting is so weird on this site. Yes, it's a duplicate, but is it such a stupid question, when "=>" is impossible to search for on Stack Overflow (it just ignores it), and Microsoft's own documentation doesn't even mention this?

Answer (score 2):

This is C#6 expression-bodied members. They let you specify the property implementation using lambda syntax.

This:

```
public string Name => Proto.Name;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
public string Name { get { return Proto.Name; } }
```

Comment: bodied properties did not implement also a setter? Just curious, i'm still learning 6.0

Comment: @Gusman They do not implement a setter, it wouldn't make sense.  For example, you could write `public string Name => "My Name";` or `public string Name => Proto.Name + " More Name";`  In that case what could it actually set?

Comment: Nice catch, thanks a lot for the info